# The excision theorem in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, nets

I am reading a book "C*-algebra and finite-Dimensional Approximations". I can not understand the proof of the excision theorem in the fundamental facts of the book.

> Theorem 1.4.10(Excision) Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $\phi$ be a pure state. There exists a net $(e_{i})\subset A$ such that $0\leq e_{i}\leq1$, $\phi(e_{i})=1$ and $\lim_{i}||e_{i}ae_{i}-\phi(a)e_{i}^{2}||=0$ for every $a\in A$.

Proof. We first assume that $A$ is unital. Let $L=\{a \in A: \phi(a^{\ast}a)=0\}$ be the left ideal associated to $\phi$ and $\{c_{i}\}$ be a right approximate unit for $L$( i.e., $\{c_{i}\}$ is an approximate unit for the hereditary subalgebra $L\cap L^{\ast}$ and for every $a\in L$ we have $||a-ac_{i}||\rightarrow0$). Let $e_{i}=1-c_{i}$. Since $a-\phi(a)\in \ker\phi=L+L^{\ast}$(if $\phi$ is a pure state, this equation is always true), we have $\lim||e_{i}(a-\phi(a))e_{i}||=0$ and $\phi(e_{i})=1$.

**Now suppose that $A$ is nonunital and take $e_{i}$ as above for $\tilde{A}$(the unitization of A). Let $\{b_{j}\}$ be a quasicentral approximate unit for $A$ such that $\phi(b_{j})=1$. (Existence follows from Kadison's Transitinity Theorem.) Then, $b_{j}e_{j}b_{j}$ does the job.**

My question: **I could not understand the sencond part of the proof. Could someone explain to me and show me some details? Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $A$ is a maximal ideal in its unitization. Then you can construct in $\tilde A$ a quasicentral approximate unit $\{b_j'\}\subset A$. Note also that a state on $A$ has a unique extension to a state in $\tilde A$; let us still call this extension $\phi$.

We also have $\limsup \phi(b_j')=1$: if $\phi(b_j')<1-\delta$ for all $j$, then $1=\phi(I)=\lim\phi(b_j'I)<1-\delta$. So by choosing a subset if necessarily, we can assume that $\phi(b_j')>1/2$, say, and so $b_j=b_j'/\phi(b_j')$ gives us our quasicentral approximate unit with $\phi(b_j)=1$.

Now apply the first part of the proof to the unital algebra $\tilde A$, to get $\{e_i\}$. Consider the net $\{b_je_kb_j\}_{k,j}$ (two indices, I don't personally see how to make the proof work if $k=j$). It is straightforward to check that this is again an approximate unit in $\tilde A$. So arguing as before we can renormalize and choose a subset to get the condition $\phi(b_je_kb_j)=1$.
Fix $\varepsilon>0$; for any $a\in A$, for $k$ big enough we have  $\|e_kae_k-\phi(a)e_k^2\|<\varepsilon$, and (recall that $\{b_j\}$ is quasicentral)
$$
\limsup_j\|b_je_kb_j\,a\,b_je_kb_j-\phi(a)(b_je_kb_j)^2\|=\limsup_j\|b_j^2(e_kae_k-\phi(a)e_k^2)b_j^2\|<\|e_kae_k-\phi(a)e_k^2\|<\varepsilon.
$$

Comment: I have three questions: 1. In the third paragraph of your proof, can we use the $\{e_{k}\}$ directly to show $lim||e_{i}(a-\phi(a))e_{i}||=0$, for every $a\in A\subseteq \tilde{A}$, instead of using the net $\{b_{j}e_{k}b_{j}\}$ ? 2. Why does the equation $lim sup ||b_{j}e_{k}b_{j}ab_{j}e_{k}b_{j}-\phi(a)(b_{j}e_{k}b_{j})^2||=lim sup ||b_{j}^2(e_{k}ae_{k}-\phi(a)e_{k}^2)b_{j}^{2}||$ holds? 3. In the proof of the theorem, how to use Kadison's Transitivity Theorem to illustrate the existence? Thanks again, Martin.

Comment: 1. No, because you want an approximate unit for all of $\tilde A$, so that you can apply the first part of the proof. \\ 2. Because $\{b_j\}$ is quasicentral; this means that it approximately commutes with all elements in $\tilde A$. \\ 3. I couldn't see how to use the Transitivity Theorem.

Comment: But I suppose, if $A$ is nonunital and we can apply the first part of the proof to take $e_{i}$ for $\tilde{A}$, then $lim||e_{i}(a-\phi(a))e_{i}||=0$, for all $a\in A\subseteq \tilde{A}$. So, we get the conclusion of the theorem. Is there anything wrong in my view?

Comment: That you cannot guarantee that $e_i\in A$.

Comment: In the part 2 of your proof, you take $b_{j}=\frac{b_{j}^{'}}{\phi(b_{j}^{'})}$. But I suppose this $b_{j}$ may not be the approximate unit, because it does not satisfy lim $a b_{j}=a$.(it satisfy lim$a b_{j}=\frac{a}{\phi({b_{j}^{'}})}$

Comment: Note first that you cannot put a $j$ on the right if you are taking a limit. In any case, the point is that one chooses a subnet with $\phi(b_j')\to1$.